# What is the best way to implement swipe navigation in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, navigation, swipe-gesture

I'm new to Angular 2 and am looking for a way to implement a good tab touch swipe navigation for mobile users with a swipe transition to the next tab view.

So far I've found a package called [angular2-useful-swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper) although am not to keen on using it as I end up initializing my components early even though they are not in view.

Does anyone know a good way to implement a tab swipe based navigation for Angular 2? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated. : )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `HammerJS` to implement for touch actions, You can follow this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/LCsiXOtzSedGZDbGQ3f8/) for example.

**Include hammer.js file**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
```

or

```
npm install hammerjs --save
```

**For browser touch support with hammerjs, include**

```
 <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/hammerjs/touchemulator/master/touch-emulator.js"></script>
<script>
```

**Import in app.module.ts**

```
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig  {
  overrides = <any>{
    'swipe': {velocity: 0.4, threshold: 20} // override default settings
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{ 
    provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, 
    useClass: MyHammerConfig 
  }] // use our custom hammerjs config
})
```

[plunker link for example](https://embed.plnkr.co/LCsiXOtzSedGZDbGQ3f8/)

To implement tabs `angular2-material` is a good place to start, follow [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/tabs)

Comment: Hammer.js is no longer maintained. Please update your answer, so others will see it right away :)

Comment: Check out the Angular [HammerModule](https://angular.dev/api/platform-browser/HammerModule?tab=description) to add HammerJS support.

Answer (score 96):

For the swipe detection here is a simpler solution than adding HammerJS:

**In app.component.html:**

```
<div (touchstart)="swipe($event, 'start')" (touchend)="swipe($event, 'end')">
  App content here
</div>
```

**In app.component.ts:**

```
private swipeCoord?: [number, number];
private swipeTime?: number;

swipe(e: TouchEvent, when: string): void {
  const coord: [number, number] = [e.changedTouches[0].clientX, e.changedTouches[0].clientY];
  const time = new Date().getTime();

  if (when === 'start') {
    this.swipeCoord = coord;
    this.swipeTime = time;
  } else if (when === 'end') {
    const direction = [coord[0] - this.swipeCoord[0], coord[1] - this.swipeCoord[1]];
    const duration = time - this.swipeTime;

    if (duration < 1000 //
      && Math.abs(direction[0]) > 30 // Long enough
      && Math.abs(direction[0]) > Math.abs(direction[1] * 3)) { // Horizontal enough
        const swipe = direction[0] < 0 ? 'next' : 'previous';
        // Do whatever you want with swipe
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I tried the HammerJS solution but configuring it to ignore mouse gestures was impossible because you don't have direct access to the Hammer object. So selecting some text was forcing navigation to the next page...

Comment: I posted your solution which is well written in a bug issue on hammer.js github, hope they will react after that on the issues we have using it ...

Comment: This is very light weight and awesome solution, only a small loophole is if you double touch next to one other(like playing a keyboard) it would detect it as a swipe.

Comment: How about this small directive https://github.com/aGoncharuks/angular-swipe-directive

Comment: @Naveed Ahmed that directive is cool but only works up to Angular 14

Answer (score 14):

I created a directive from @Elvis Metodiev answer and @pikiou :

> swipe.directive.ts

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[swipe]' })
export class SwipeDirective {

    @Output() next = new EventEmitter<void>();
    @Output() previous = new EventEmitter<void>();

    swipeCoord = [0, 0];
    swipeTime = new Date().getTime();

    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event']) onSwipeStart($event) {
        this.onSwipe($event, 'start');
    }

    @HostListener('touchend', ['$event']) onSwipeEnd($event) {
        this.onSwipe($event, 'end');
    }

    onSwipe(e: TouchEvent, when: string) {
        this.swipe(e, when);
    }

    swipe(e: TouchEvent, when: string): void {

        const coord: [number, number] = [e.changedTouches[0].clientX, e.changedTouches[0].clientY];
        const time = new Date().getTime();

        if (when === 'start') {
            this.swipeCoord = coord;
            this.swipeTime = time;
        } else if (when === 'end') {
            const direction = [coord[0] - this.swipeCoord[0], coord[1] - this.swipeCoord[1]];
            const duration = time - this.swipeTime;

            if (duration < 1000 //
                && Math.abs(direction[0]) > 30 // Long enough
                && Math.abs(direction[0]) > Math.abs(direction[1] * 3)) { // Horizontal enough
                const swipeDir = direction[0] < 0 ? 'next' : 'previous';
                if (swipeDir === 'next') {
                    this.next.emit();
                } else {
                    this.previous.emit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> tour.component.component.ts

```html
<div
  ...
  swipe
  (next)="onRotateNext()"
  (previous)="onRotatePrevious()"
>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

First install hammerjs and action touch-action polyfill:

```
$ npm install hammerjs hammer-timejs
```

Then add the imports to 'app.module.ts' so they will be used/bundled:

```
import 'hammerjs';
import 'hammer-timejs';
```

Now you can handle the events for the actions:
Rotate
Pinch
Press
Pan
Tap
Swipe

For example you can say:

```html
<li *ngFor="let employee of employeesList;" (swiperight)="myswiperight(employee)" (swipeleft)="myswipeleft(employee)">
```

Or:

```html
<div (panstart)="onPanStart($event)" (panmove)="onPan($event)">
```

Reference: https://saschwarz.github.io/angular2-gestures-slides/#/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a write-once-use-everywhere type of function which I put in a dir called "gestures" and then created a file called "swipe.ts" and put this inside.

```
let swipeCoord = [0, 0];
let swipeTime = new Date().getTime();

export function swipe(e: TouchEvent, when: string): void {

    const coord: [number, number] = [e.changedTouches[0].clientX, e.changedTouches[0].clientY];
    const time = new Date().getTime();

    if (when === 'start') {
        swipeCoord = coord;
        swipeTime = time;
    } else if (when === 'end') {
        const direction = [coord[0] - swipeCoord[0], coord[1] - swipeCoord[1]];
        const duration = time - swipeTime;

        if (duration < 1000 //
            && Math.abs(direction[0]) > 30 // Long enough
            && Math.abs(direction[0]) > Math.abs(direction[1] * 3)) { // Horizontal enough
            const swipeDir = direction[0] < 0 ? 'next' : 'previous';
            if (swipeDir === 'next') {
                alert('swipe next');
            } else {
                alert('swipe prev');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then import into the desired component, like so:

```
import {swipe} from '../../gestures/swipe';
```

And create a function called:

```
onSwipe(e: TouchEvent, when: string) {
        swipe(e, when);
    }
```

In the HTML of the desired component, go with this:

```
    <div (touchstart)="onSwipe($event, 'start')"
         (touchend)="onSwipe($event, 'end')">

       <!-- whatever content you have goes here -->

    </div>
```

PS - credit goes to @pikiou. I just came up with a higher level of abstraction, which to me makes a lot more sense.