# How to enable swipe gesture to move to next tab for tabs module in Angular Material? (looking for a solution that works for more than 2 tabs)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the tabs component in angular material: https://material.angular.io/components/component/tabs

Is there a way to make it such that I can swipe on the content area of the tab to trigger moving to the next tab?

My current template html:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I have hammerjs imported, and the documentation appears to not mention anything about this even though I could have sworn I've seen something like this before...

Specifically I want to be able to click and drag my mouse towards the left to have it swipe left to the left tab. And click and drag my mouse towards the right to have it swipe right ot the right tab.

Comment: It does not state that tab supports gesture. See step 5: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 12):

here is a simple way to do it:

> working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uJ3n8XedvCCdeUHXKpwX?p=preview

first, add hammerjs to your module:

`import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

provide it in `providers`

```js
  providers: [{ 
                    provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, 
                    useClass: HammerGestureConfig 
                }]
```

sample module:

```js
@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
  ],

  declarations: [TabsOverviewExample],
  bootstrap: [TabsOverviewExample],
  providers: [{ 
                    provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, 
                    useClass: HammerGestureConfig 
                }]
})
export class PlunkerAppModule {}
```

then build your component like this:

```js
import {Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';
import { MdTabGroup, MdTab } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'tabs-overview-example',
  template:`
  <md-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected"  (swipeleft)="swipe($event.type)" (swiperight)="swipe($event.type)">
    <md-tab label="Tab 1"><div class="content">Content 1</div></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab 2"><div class="content">Content 2</div></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab 3"><div class="content">Content 3</div></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab 4"><div class="content">Content 4</div></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab 5"><div class="content">Content 5</div></md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>`,
  styles:['.content{ height: 500px; background-color: yellow;}']
})
export class TabsOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild(MdTabGroup) group;
  @ViewChildren(MdTab) tabs;
  tab_num = 0;
  selected = 0;
  SWIPE_ACTION = { LEFT: 'swipeleft', RIGHT: 'swiperight' };

  number_tabs
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.tab_num = this.tabs.length
    console.log(this.group)
  }
  swipe(eType){
    console.log(eType);
    if(eType === this.SWIPE_ACTION.LEFT && this.selected > 0){
      console.log("movin left")
      this.selected--;
    }
    else if(eType === this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT && this.selected < this.tab_num){
      console.log("movin right")
      this.selected++;
    }
    console.log(this.selected)
  }


}
```

Comment: Beware that HammerJS is getting deprecated! Consider another approach

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

https://plnkr.co/edit/VC270mPwh2o8CbMt9u7k?p=preview

Template

```
<div class="md-content" flex md-scroll-y (swipeleft)="swipe(idx, $event.type)" (swiperight)="swipe(idx, $event.type)">
<md-tab-group md-stretch-tabs [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex" (selectedIndexChange)="selectChange()">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1" (swipeleft)="swipe(1, $event.type)" (swiperight)="swipe(1, $event.type)">
      Content 1
    </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2" (swipeleft)="swipe(2, $event.type)" (swiperight)="swipe(2, $event.type)">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
</div>
```

Component

```
export class TabsOverviewExample {


  selectedIndex: number = 1;

  selectChange(): void{
    console.log("Selected INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
  }

  SWIPE_ACTION = { LEFT: 'swipeleft', RIGHT: 'swiperight' };

  // Action triggered when user swipes
  swipe(selectedIndex: number, action = this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
  console.log("swipe");
    console.log("number",selectedIndex);
    console.log("action",action);
    // Out of range
    if (this.selectedIndex < 0 || this.selectedIndex > 1 ) return;

    // Swipe left, next tab
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.LEFT) {
      const isLast = this.selectedIndex === 1;
      this.selectedIndex = isLast ? 0 : this.selectedIndex + 1;
      console.log("Swipe right - INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
    }

    // Swipe right, previous tab
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
      const isFirst = this.selectedIndex === 0;
      this.selectedIndex = isFirst ? 1 : this.selectedIndex - 1;
      console.log("Swipe left - INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Parth can please explain what is idx in  (swipeleft)="swipe(idx, $event.type)"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of @ahmed-musallam's answer using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511007/1785552):

**Template:**

```html
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup [selectedIndex]="selected" (touchstart)="swipe($event, 'start')" (touchend)="swipe($event, 'end')">
...
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Component:**

```ts
@ViewChild('tabGroup', { static: true }) tabGroup: MatTabGroup;
public selected: number;
private swipeCoord?: [number, number];
private swipeTime?: number;
swipe(e: TouchEvent, when: string): void {
    const coord: [number, number] = [e.changedTouches[0].clientX, e.changedTouches[0].clientY];
    const time = new Date().getTime();

    if (when === 'start') {
        this.swipeCoord = coord;
        this.swipeTime = time;
    } else if (when === 'end') {
        const direction = [coord[0] - this.swipeCoord[0], coord[1] - this.swipeCoord[1]];
        const duration = time - this.swipeTime;

        if (duration < 1000 //
            && Math.abs(direction[0]) > 30 // Long enough
            && Math.abs(direction[0]) > Math.abs(direction[1] * 3)) { // Horizontal enough
            const swipe = direction[0] < 0 ? 'next' : 'previous';
            switch (swipe) {
                case 'previous':
                    if (this.selected > 0) { this.selected--; }
                    break;
                case 'next':
                    if (this.selected < this.tabGroup._tabs.length - 1) { this.selected++; }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to switch 'previous' and 'next' for RTL direction.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code but in accepted answers the html tags used were not matching the library I was using. Worked for with a slight modification of initializing this.selected = this.tabGroup.selectedIndex;

Answer (score 1):

By this current code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43752352/9026103) it works, but with 2 tabs only because you need to set tabsCount instead of literal 1. The solution implemented only for two tabs.

Below some improved solution for any count of tabs.

Working sandbox with the newest material here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nqeiw

Credits to this guy -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43752352/9026103

```
export class TabsOverviewExample {


  selectedIndex: number = 1;
  tabsCount = 3;

  selectChange(): void{
    console.log("Selected INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
  }

  SWIPE_ACTION = { LEFT: 'swipeleft', RIGHT: 'swiperight' };

  // Action triggered when user swipes
  swipe(selectedIndex: number, action = this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
  console.log("swipe");
    console.log("number",selectedIndex);
    console.log("action",action);
    // Out of range
    if (this.selectedIndex < 0/* starter point as 0 */ || this.selectedIndex > this.tabsCount/* here it is */ ) return;

    // Swipe left, next tab
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.LEFT) {
      const isLast = this.selectedIndex === this.tabsCount;
      this.selectedIndex = isLast ? 0 : this.selectedIndex + 1;
      console.log("Swipe right - INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
    }

    // Swipe right, previous tab
    if (action === this.SWIPE_ACTION.RIGHT) {
      const isFirst = this.selectedIndex === 0 /* starter point as 0 */;
      this.selectedIndex = isFirst ? 1 : this.selectedIndex - 1;
      console.log("Swipe left - INDEX: " + this.selectedIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the proposed solutions support interactive swipe gestures. If you need it; consider using a library like [SwiperJs](https://swiperjs.com/).